# Unable to change express-session expiry date in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I am using express-session in my project.
Suppose that a session has been instantiated between web browser and node js server with a default expiry time of an hour.
A cookie with connect.sid name is available in browser now.

And I need a function to extend the expiry datetime in both user browser and node js.
How could it be done?

I have done it in server side with following ways but it does not reflect in user browser.
Is there any possible to push new expiry datetime to user browser cookie?

```
var hour = 3600000;
req.session.cookie.expires = new Date(Date.now() + hour);
req.session.cookie.maxAge = hour;
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading/writing cookies in the browser is slightly different to how you manipulate cookies in node.js. In the browser, cookies are stored as a property of the `document` object, namely `document.cookie`, as a string of key value pairs separated by semi-colons.

Here's a simple function which lets you create/modify a cookie (the browser handles the logic which overwrites existing cookies):

```
function createCookie (name, value, days) {
  var expires = ""
  var date = new Date()
  if (days) {
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
    expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString()
  }
  document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/"    
}
```

So in your case, you'd simply call:

```
var hour = 3600000;
createCookie('expires', new Date(Date.now() + hour), 1); // I've arbitrarily chosen one day as the expiry here
createCookie('maxAge', hour, 1); // here too
```

Or something to that effect. Hope this helps!